# Есть массив 4 на 8 нужно найти самый большой по модулю элемент массива и отсортировать столбец в котором он находиться за убыванием

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Есть массив 4 на 8 нужно найти самый большой по модулю элемент массива и отсортировать столбец в котором он находиться за убыванием
вот пример кода на с++ билдер но мне нужно на с++, у меня не получаеться, помогите пожалуйста, очень прошу

```
int mas[3][3];
int max,i,j,str,stol;
max=abs(mas[0][0]);
for (i=1; i>3; i++)
for (j=1; j>3; j++)
mas[i][j]=StrToInt(StringGrid2->Cells[i][j]);
if (abs(mas[i][j])>max) {max=abs(mas[i][j]);
str=i;
stol=j;}
Label8->Caption=IntToStr(max);
Label9->Caption=IntToStr(str);
Label10->Caption=IntToStr(stol);
}
```

Comment: 1) Так 3 на 3 массив или 4 на 8? В цикле `i = 1` и `j = 1` вы пропускаете целую строчку и столбец, а не один символ как вы наверно думали. 2) В чем конкретно проблема? Вы нашли максимальное число, его индексы по строке и столбцу. Теперь просто реализуйте например [пузырьковый алгоритм](https://nicknixer.ru/programmirovanie/algoritm-puzyrkovoj-sortirovki-odnomernogo-massiva-na-c/) сортировки по столбцу. И все!

Comment: мне нужно написать этот код на с++ а у меня не выходит его реализация. Массив нужен 4 на 8

Comment: Ну так просто реализуйте пузырьковый алгоритм по столбцу, пример есть по ссылке в предыдущем комментарии.

Comment: я не понимаю как реализовать этот код в с++

Comment: Да в смысле как? Код по ссылке на `c++` написан. Вам целое приложение с окном и элементами нужно сделать?

Comment: мне нужно сделать массив 4 на 8 найти в нем самый большой элемент по модулю и только столбец в котором есть этот элемент отсортировать по убыванию

Comment: В общем присмотрелся к вашему коду и понял, что в нем куча ошибок. [Найти максимальный элемент в матрице](https://taskcode.ru/matrix/max-columns), потом [пузырьковый алгоритм](https://nicknixer.ru/programmirovanie/algoritm-puzyrkovoj-sortirovki-odnomernogo-massiva-na-c/). Все чем могу помочь